# Rails 5 Debug in Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am trying to find a way to check logs or debug in production I am using passenger and apache and ubuntu as server. Every time I create any scaffold and upload it to server I get error :
[image]

I have used

```
 bundle exec rake  assets:precompile  RAILS_ENV=production
```

But getting no success but when I am running application using :

```
 rails s -e production
```

I can access my controllers and views over port 3000. What is wrong with this why assets:precompile is not working properly I am adding JS files manually not using coffee script. And my javascripts files are not complied.

My question is how can I set anything in production to see a debug like in development mode like this: 
[image]

Can I do this in production I am using rails 5

Comment: are your logs not in the rails `log` dir?

Comment: just have passenger log I don't know what is the problem why I am getting these error  need to find the problem. no logs in production.log it is empty.

Comment: what do you mean by you `assets:precompile` is failing? what error messages are you getting?

Comment: I added javascript files and when I upload it to server after precompile changes are not visible

Answer (score 1):

The production error you have shown above was a 404 error. it means that the route doesn't exist or there are no controllers methods for that route or is a model not found error.

**As for adding debuggers in production, can you do it?**

Yes you can.

**But should you do it?**

**NO**, because it is a **BAD** practice. If you wish to view and debug errors in production, check your logs for the stacktrace and work with it from there. As long as it is a rails error, it will be in `log/production.log`.